# please help translate the signature! (Characters identified: 大明永樂年施)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

This is the signature on the pair sculptures. I translated only one word (the right one) - 大 "big", but other I can't recognize. Please, help

[image]

Comment: I was going to say it read 大明永樂年製 <Made during the Ming dynasty Yongle era (1403－1424)> but the last character looks different from the 製 in seal script. I would like to know what else besides 製 can follow 大明永樂年 in this mark

Comment: Yes, the last word is "施" (說文小篆), who identified it? applaudable! :)

Answer (score 2):

大明  - Ming dynasty

永樂年 - Yongle era (1403－1424)

施 - Applied; carried out

So, basically, this mark told you the sculptures were made between 1403 and 1424. Not a signature